# Get the pandas dtype representation of interval

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, metadata

I've written some code that converts some input data to pandas data frame, making sure that date & time fields are converted to the relevant data type (Timestamp and Timedelta).

In my tests I'm writting asserts for the dtypes of the columns, it look like that:

```
test_data_frame = input_data_to_df(test_data) # type: pd.DataFrame

self.assertEquals(
    pandas.core.dtypes.dtype.DatetimeTZDtype.construct_from_string('datetime64[ns, UTC]')
    test_data_frame['timestamp_column'].dtype)
```

This works well fo column of type `datetime64[ns, UTC]` or any `datetime64`

I'm trying to do the same thing with a column of type `timedelta64[ns]` but I can't get  the relevant dtype representation.

- This doesn't work `DatetimeTZDtype.construct_from_string('timedelta64[ns]')`
- `IntervalDtype.construct_from_string('timedelta64[ns]')` returns an `interval[timedelta64[ns]]` which isn't what I want

Comment: Please share the sample input data and an expected output

Comment: should just be the numpy dtype: `np.dtype('timedelta64[ns]')`